# Genesis 34:2-3 according to DRB, does it seem to be an ordinary rape or forced seduction or just a seduction?

Tags: genesis

Genesis 34:2-3 (DRB):

> 2 And when Sichem the son of Hemor the Hevite, the prince of that land, saw her, he was in love with her: and took her away, and lay with her, ravishing the virgin.
>   3 And his soul was fast knit unto her, and whereas she was sad, he comforted her with sweet words.

Does it seem [**a forced seduction**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forced_seduction) rather than **an ordinary rape**, or just a seduction in Douay-Rheims Bible (DRB)?

Forced seduction: wherein man-on-woman rape eventually turns into a genuine love affair.

Forced seduction is a theme found in western literature.

There are three opinions about what happened to Dinah by sichem:

- Ordinary rape.
- Forced seduction.
- Just seduction.

In any of the three cases, Dinah was seized by Sichem.

In any of the three cases, Sichem fall in love with Dinah.

Comment: Why down votes?, I think it is a good question.

Comment: Forced seduction is a theme found in western literature.

Comment: @NigelJ the point is that: you understand me, I mean I am talking about special kind of rape which develops into a genuine love affair. Again!, The point is: you understand what I mean.

Comment: You seem to have not a single clue how offensive your words are : talking about 'love affair' and 'rape' in the same sentence. Discussion over. No further comment, thanks very much.

Comment: @salah I, too, found your question jarring. If it had been your first ques. on BH, I may have chalked it up to a desire for shock value. However, I've pondered the passage a bit and sense there is more to it than other stark rape passages in the Bible. Correct or not, I chose to think that is what you were trying to convey. It offered an opportunity to put my views up for scrutiny in the BH community, tho a short-lived opportunity if you insist on defending the, imo, indefensible concept of 'forced seduction' in relation to the Bible.

Comment: @tblue thank you for your comment, I will try to modify the post.

Comment: @salah Not there yet. 'Forced seduction', to me,  just has no *Biblical* application. I could see 'authority/power rape' whereby someone in lower rank feels compelled by the desires of someone in higher authority - applying, perhaps, to Shechem/Dinah or David/Bathsheba. Even if 'forced seduction' occurs outside of smut romance novels, it has no place, that I can see, in Bible discussions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the DRB translation misses the mark for melding with the Hebrew.

"Forcible seduction", sounds like a contradiction of terms. And comparing it to 'ordinary' rape - is just...odd.

That said, there is a wide range of viewpoints in commentaries as to what some feel transpired between Shechem and Dinah.

To date, my personal view is that Shechem's actions were 'calculated'. Prince or no, he was a Hivite/Canaanite - lineage of Ham. Cursed by Noah. Later, in Exodus and Deuteronomy, intermarriage between Canaanites and Israelites would be formally banned.

Perhaps Shechem deduced that the only way he could circumvent such a stigma and marry Dinah was to first lay with her. Then Abraham would be compelled to agree to marriage.

Maybe it *was* a mutual attraction/love at first site deal and the 'sweet words' to Dinah ran along the lines of, "this is the only way we can be together always". Who knows, but it's possible that Shechem had a Plan, a 'bright idea' (based on his actions afterward in asking for marriage/circumcision,and Dinah remaining in his abode).

Regardless, the questions I find more intriguing:

a. Was Dinah impregnated by Shechem?

b. What's up with Dinah being referred to as 'naor' (Heb. N-O-R) rather than 'naorah' (f) for 'maiden' (even after the encounter)? Preliminary speculation makes me wonder if Dinah was blonde (and Moses, in the basket, was 'naor'...blonde and not a 'lad', etc.) It's a study in progress.

Comment: forced seduction is a term, there is a page on Wikipedia regarding this term.

Comment: @NigelJ the point is: you understand me, you understand what I mean. This is the point.